# Dropdown getting displayed under the caracole Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

With my Nav's dropdowns it wont display correctly.
Somehow the drop-down will go under caracole. It's annoying and weird.
I'm using BSv3.0.3 JS and CSS match versions. 
It's most notable when you look at the servers > hub link. You can't click it. 
Head to [fgkservers.com](http://FGKServers.com/#top) and go to the secon slide. Click servers in the nav and try going to the link hub. Won't let you.

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
         <div class="navbar-header">
           <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></a>
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="">MC.FastFoodCraft.COM</a>
         </div>
         <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#top">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#rules">Rules</a></li>
              <li><a href="/#donate">Donate</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="" name="servers" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Servers <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#factions">Factions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#teampvp">TeamPvP</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#skywars">SkyWars</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#prison">Prison</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#hub">Hub</a></li>
                </ul>
             <li><a href="/bans">Bans</a></li>
             <li><a href="/vote">Vote</a></li>
             <li><a href="/forum">Forums</a></li>
             </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div><!-- /container -->
</div><!-- /navbar wrapper -->  


<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li><li data-target="#" data-slide-to="1"></li><li data-target="#" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="/img/1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Welcome to FastFoodCraft!</h1>
          <p></p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-info" href="#about">About Us</a>
        </p></div></div></div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="/img/2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Factions | TeamPvP | SkyWars | Prison</h1>
          <p>All the servers, all in one great place! </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#factions">More Info</a></p></div></div> </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="/img/3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Join using MC.FastFoodCraft.com</h1>
          <p>Play Minecraft with us! </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="http://minecraft.net" target="_blank">Minecraft.net</a></p></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Thanks for your help
- Fred

Comment: It seems to work properly for me .. I just changed the `<img src="">`
Link -> http://www.bootply.com/118556.. Do check out your `z-index`

Comment: @megesh its going under my text not my photo. Head [here](http://Fgkservers.com/#top) to look at the live preview. If i find out how to fix it I will answer my own question.